# ssh remote call which executes nohup inside the execution exits in very short time

Tags: bash, session, ssh, remote-access, nohup

I have some test bash file like below (`test.sh` with 755 mod)

```
#! /bin/bash
nohup /usr/bin/java -Xms4g -Xmx4g  -Dspring.profiles.active=test -jar /home/users/me/test.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &
exit 1
```

then I execute this file over ssh like

```
$> ssh test@server /home/users/me/sh/test.sh
```

while it runs, I repeat execute `jps` on `test@server` to monitor the process. I can see test.jar in the prompt, but certain point it disappears like about 1~2 seconds after remote ssh command execution.

like ..

```
test@server /home/users/me: jps
1281492 Jps
1281485 test.jar
test@server /home/users/me: jps
1281546 Jps
1281485 test.jar
test@server /home/users/me: jps
1281580 Jps
```

In my opinion the `java` job should last since it works with `nohup`. Any idea of cause? Thanx

===== updates

In my case, the problem was ssh working directory. As RenaudPacalet mentioned in the comment, I was able to figure out by directing nohup output into a log file.

More specific, Spring boot jar finds `config` directory when it starts up. I got my config directory like `/home/users/me/config`.

So when I send command via ssh, boot tried to start up(That is why I could watch `test.jar` in `jps` in short time) but it failed since it does not know where to loop up configs.(because I did not state where to execute the command)

In conclusion, I have to fix like below

```
$> ssh test@server 'cd /home/users/me; /home/users/me/sh/test.sh'
```

Comment: Is there a `nohup.out` file? If yes looking at its content could help. Else, redirecting to a log file instead of `/dev/null` could also help.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks. replacing `/dev/null` with log file works for me. I found some application problems in the log b b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if all of the paths are correct in the script, and test the script without using nohup first to see if any errors occur, and to know if the script has any errors, then you can use nohup and troubleshoot nohup from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think my original question was too wide because it has several problems at once.

So I would like to close this Question by explain how I solved this specific case. The main problem does not in `nohup`, but directing nohup output to a log file was obviously helpful.

Like I wrote in the original post `update` section. When execute a command over ssh, one should care where the command executes exactly.

So I solved this problem by moving working directory like this

```
$> ssh test@server 'cd /home/users/me; /home/users/me/sh/test.sh'
```